# How do I apply conditional formatting in .map() in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I have the below data

```
[
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "SIZE": 2.21,
    "Metal": "Steel",
    "Class": "Non magnetic",
    "Density":3.9,
    
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "SIZE": 1.25,
    "Metal": "Iron",
    "Class": "magnetic",
    "Density":4.2,
    
  },
  {
    "ID": "3",
    "SIZE": 15.5,
    "Metal": "Water",
    "Class": "non magnetic",
    "Density": 1.3,
  },
  {
    "ID": "4",
    "SIZE": 9.5,
    "Metal": "Steel",
    "Class": "non magnetic",
    "Density": 1.2,
  }
  {
    "ID": "5",
    "SIZE": 3.2,
    "Metal": "Water",
    "Class": "non magnetic",
    "Density": 1.0,
  }
]
```

Goal is to create a new map and filter the data. If name is steel or iron, we need to get the size from the previous object . Likewise if metal is water, then we need to the skip the currect object and check in the next value in the next object. If the subsequent values are water too, then we need to return "Invalid". I tried the below piece of code but it is not returning the desired output

```
data.map((temp, i) =>{ 
                    if (temp.METAL.toUpperCase() != 'WATER')
                    {
                        res.push({
                            ID: temp.ID,
                            SIZE: temp.SIZE,
                            Priortosize: data[i + 1] ? data[i + 1].SIZE: "Invalid",
                            Metal: temp.METAL
                            Class: temp.CLASS,
                            Density: temp.DENSITY
                    })
                    }
                
            })
```

It returns empty value if the last metal is water. Can you please help?

Comment: "It returns empty value if the last metal is water."  **Yes, thats what it does** It skips the item when metal is water. The code inside the if statement will run when metal is not water.  There is no code that runs when it is water.  Also, the code shows that the return from `map` is discarded and instead `res.push` is used to build a result.  This is inconsistent with best practice.  To be consistent, perhaps you want either a `.forEach` instead of map --- or a `return` instead of `res.push` with map,

Comment: can you suggest an alternate logic?

Comment: Don't use `.map()` if you mean to do `.forEach()`

Comment: I need seperate logic if metal is water or steel and iron. For steel and iron it should be "N/A" and for water it should be empty

Answer (score 1):

First, Javascript is a case-sensitive language.

```js
data.Metal != data.METAL
```

Use `data.Metal`, just as it is in the data object.

I also saw that you forgot some commas in your example, both in the data object and in the push of your code.

```js
data = [
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "SIZE": 2.21,
    "Metal": "Steel",
    "Class": "Non magnetic",
    "Density":3.9,
    
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "SIZE": 1.25,
    "Metal": "Iron",
    "Class": "magnetic",
    "Density":4.2,
    
  },
  {
    "ID": "3",
    "SIZE": 15.5,
    "Metal": "Water",
    "Class": "non magnetic",
    "Density": 1.3,
  },
  {
    "ID": "4",
    "SIZE": 9.5,
    "Metal": "Steel",
    "Class": "non magnetic",
    "Density": 1.2,
  },
  {
    "ID": "5",
    "SIZE": 3.2,
    "Metal": "Water",
    "Class": "non magnetic",
    "Density": 1.0,
  }
]

res = []

data.map((temp, i) =>{ 
                    if (temp.Metal.toUpperCase() != 'WATER')
                    {
                        res.push({
                            ID: temp.ID,
                            SIZE: temp.SIZE,
                            Priortosize: data[i + 1] ? data[i + 1].SIZE: "Invalid",
                            Metal: temp.Metal,
                            Class: temp.Class,
                            Density: temp.Density
                    })
                    }
                
            })
            
console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 0))
```

Comment: I missed out on the commas and cases while reproducing the code...However the logic is same and it doesn't work in all the cases. Can you suggest an alternative one?

Comment: "If the subsequent values are water too, then we need to return "Invalid"" all subsequent values ?

Comment: the logic is if it is water the next hole size should be empty if there are no more metals(iron and steel). If it is iron or steel we'll return the nextholesize or "n/a"